# How to convert gallery Images To PDF using iText in android?

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to convert gallery images to PDF using iTextbut not able to get the PDF File with Images.
Here i tried to convert images to PDF :-

```
void getListOfFiles()
    {
    File root = new File(Environment
              .getExternalStorageDirectory()
              .getAbsolutePath()+"/xxx/Images/FeatureId/");
            ListDir(root);
}

     private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
     void ListDir(File f){
         File[] files = f.listFiles();
         fileList.clear();
         for (File file : files){
          fileList.add(file.getPath());  
         }
     }

    public void convertimagetopdf(){
        getListOfFiles();
        Document document=new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/xxx/Images/Image.pdf"));
            document.open();
            for (int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++) {
                Image image = Image.getInstance (fileList.get(i));
                   // document.add(new Paragraph("TouchBase"));

                    document.add(image);    

            }

             document.close(); 

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Here i am getting error in **Log-cat**:-

```
06-10 14:17:56.897: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.897: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.897: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.907: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.907: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphicsShapes
06-10 14:17:56.907: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createGraphicsShapes
06-10 14:17:56.907: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.917: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.917: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.917: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics
06-10 14:17:56.927: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphicsShapes
06-10 14:17:56.927: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.awt.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphicsShapes
06-10 14:17:56.987: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.PixelGrabber', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance
06-10 14:17:56.987: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance
06-10 14:17:57.898: E/dalvikvm(29483): Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj
```

When i open my directory to view PDF file which created at the given path.it show me error :corrupt or Unsupported format.But created pdf file showing 870kb size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is other files working properly?

Comment: @mona  i dont understand what other files you are talking about.

Comment: i mean lets say text file or doc file is that getting converted to pdf?

Comment: @mona Yes If i tried to convert single image  to PDf it convert. but when i tried to load images from folder it says corrupt or Unsupported format when i open PDF.